# Python code for Speech Recognition not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-speech-api

I went through all the similar questions on this topic and tried everything, but nothing's working.

I tried solutions from the following links :
[speech recognition python stopped in listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043091/speech-recognition-python-stopped-in-listen)
[SpeechRecognition producing OSError: No Default Input Device Available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56096427/speechrecognition-producing-oserror-no-default-input-device-available)
[Python, Speech Recognition stuck at 'Listening...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62401885/python-speech-recognition-stuck-at-listening)
[speech recognition python code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005310/speech-recognition-python-code-not-working)  etc.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def get_audio():
    r =  sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=5)
        print("listening... ")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

    return said.lower()         

print(get_audio())
```

Error that I am getting is:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Following command gets stuck at 'Say Something..' and does nothing.

```
 python -m speech_recognition
```

I also tried following code to check the default audio device :

```
import pyaudio
print(pyaudio.pa.get_default_input_device())
```

Ouput :

```
OSError: No Default Input Device Available
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you tell your PC specs

Comment: By the way it clearly says that you have no microphone available

Comment: PC Specs: Windows 8.1, 8 GB RAM.  But I am able to record the audio and save it in a file using pyaudio.

Comment: Can you provide the screen shot

Comment: screenshot of what?

Comment: Just go and right click on the speaker icon and select the recording devices. The window that appears

Comment: The recording device is working fine. Like I told you I am able to record and save the audio file

Comment: I don't know why, but also put try and catch before `with sr.Microphone() as source:`

Comment: Okay! so the code is all correct by you but there is some microphone configuration problem. The code works all fine for me atleast

Comment: Hey have you fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments above, you don't seem to have any microphone available.

When using Speech Recognition, I usually ask the user which device to use before listening.

For example, using this implementation:

```
# Identify the microphone device to use
def get_microphone_device():
    microphone_list = []
    for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
        microphone_list.append("Microphone {1} `(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))

    questions = [
    inquirer.List('microphone',
            message = "What Microphone will you use?",
            choices = microphone_list,
        ),
    ]
    answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
    microphone = answers["microphone"]
    microphone = re.search("(?=`)(.*)", microphone).group(0)
    device = re.search("[0-9]", microphone).group()
    return device
```

And then, to use the device and get the message, you can follow as you did, for example:

```
# Listen to the speaker through the microphone device
def get_speech(device):
    rec = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=int(device)) as source:
        print("Speak, we are listening:")
        audio = rec.listen(source)
        try:
            text = rec.recognize_google(audio)
            print("You said: \"{}\"".format(text))
        except:
            print("Sorry, we couldn't recognize what you said")
    return text
```

[Here is an example of the full implementation](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-python/blob/master/speech/recognition/src/formula/formula.py)

I hope it helped!